# Modify join table to reference different tables and rename

Tags: elixir, ecto

I currently have a table called `leagues_questions`, but during development I've realized that the table should be called `seasons_questions` and reference the `season` table instead of the `question` table. I'm struggling to understand to best way to make this change. My first thought is to create a new migration that will modify this table. Here is my attempt:

#### Old Migration:

```
def change do
  create table(:leagues_questions, primary_key: false) do
    add :id, :uuid, primary_key: true
    add :league_id, references(:leagues, on_delete: :nothing, type: :uuid), null: false
    add :question_id, references(:questions, on_delete: :nothing, type: :uuid), null: false

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

#### NEW  Migration:

```
def change do
  alter table(:questions_leagues) do
    modify :question_id, :season_id
  end
end
```

*I also need to change the table name but I think I can handle that.*

I don't think this will work and I haven't really even tried it yet, because I don't know how to change the `references` part. How can I modify the references column of a table within a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename the column you need to do

```
rename table(:leagues_questions), :question_id, to: :season_id
```

Then you need to deal with the foreign key constraints

I'm assuming you've already tried this:

```
alter table(:leagues_questions) do
  modify :season_id, references(:seasons, on_delete: :nothing, type: :uuid), null: false)
end
```

and it didn't work. You need to do this:

```
drop constraint("leagues_questions", :leagues_questions_question_id_fkey)
alter table(:leagues_questions) do
  modify :season_id, references(:seasons, on_delete: :nothing, type: :uuid), null: false)
end
```

Basically drop the existing constraint first.